# How can i execute the following manual method through cmd or PowerShell commands?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have some manual checks which includes:

Click **Start** > Type in **local security policy**. Once open, navigate to **Local Policies** > **User Rights Assignments** and then in the right pane look for the row that says **Access this computer from the network** and ensure that only “**Authenticated users**” is listed.

If this is on a domain controller then ensure that both “**authenticated users**” and “**Enterprise Domain Controllers**” is configured.

Following is the sample screenshot however, the actual settings might be different. The target machines could be Windows Server 2012r2, 2016

[image]

Could anyone please suggest if i can do this using command line or PowerShell commands?

Comment: Yes, see e.g. https://serverfault.com/q/848388.

Comment: @iRon: Thanks, with that post, i was able to download the list of Registry locations where these settings can be checked however, for Windows 2012R2, 2016, these settings are not available as per the list.

Comment: HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network Connections!NC_AdvancedSettings
is available for Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000 Service Pack 1 operating systems only

Comment: Why do this manually for a host, especially for a domain joined device, if that is where you are. This is what Group Policy/GPP is specifically designed for.

Comment: @postanote: I get that but the issue is for Windows Server 2016 and 2012R2, these registry values are not available.

Comment: I was not saying edit the registry directly, but use GP/GPP from your DC to set this on the planned targets. So, are you saying, you cannot find these regkeys? Did you fire up SysInternals tools to monitor registry changes, made this change on at least one server and see the hive that was touched?

Comment: @postanote: I am new to these configurations hence not sure to check this. What i did was, tried to check the available registry locations (as Microsoft per sheet which shares the location of all the policies and the supported windows version against them). I tried manually browsing to the registry location where we can check these settings. Unfortunately, for Win Server 2012R2, this was not available. Would you mind if you could please share the steps to do this by other ways. Unfortunately, i am novice to these settings.

Comment: Just download the MS Sysinternals Suite - https://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip --- and run Process Monitor v3.50 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon  --- Using Process Monitor to track registry changes --- https://superuser.com/questions/317877/using-process-monitor-to-track-registry-changes --- the open your MMC and make the change, the procmon will show you what changed.